# How to phrase a null hypothesis for regression model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I'm measuring the popularity of two candy bars (Mars and Twix).

I'm comparing the popularity scores of the two candy bars in a regression model.

My model features 'candy bar' (with Mars as the reference group), as well as 'gender', 'age', and 'car ownership status'.

My alternative hypothesis: Twix is associated with higher popularity scores than Maars after adjusting for all other predictors.

I struggle writing a null hypothesis. I know what I want to say (there is no difference between the candy bars) but how would you phrase that?

Thanks

Comment: If you alternative hypothesis is that twix is associated with higher popularity, then the null would be that mars is at least as popular as twix.  If your null were that there is no difference, your 5% or whatever p-value you use would get split between one better or the other, so it can affect your result.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Twix is associated with higher popularity scores than Mars"?

I'm not sure what you mean by "after adjusting for all other predictors", if you are only interest in average popularity over the population.

Was each respondent was asked to score "I prefer Twix to Mars" on a Likert scale? If so, I understand why you are talking about a regression model. But if the question was "Do you prefer Twix or Mars" then the model is a classifier.

Alternatively, were there two Likert scales: "1. how much do you like Twix? 2. How much do you like Mars?" In this case you could have a more complicated null hypothesis: after taking into account other factors, which bar is on offer does not significantly influence how much it is liked.

This last formulation of the problem allows you to detect results like male car owners prefer Twix and women prefer Mars.